# I'm encountering an error when I change the column names in a Model-View-Controller app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio, and I followed the tutorial to create a Model-View-Controller Movie Database. Link to tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

My Goal: to replace the names of the columns that appear when running the app.

In the Models folder is a C# file named Movie.cs. It contains the class Movie. Adapting the program for my own purposes, I made the following changes:

- Title to Name
- ReleaseDate to Date
- Genre to Email
- Price to Contract

I'm including the code from the Movie.cs file below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public decimal Contract { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After making those changes, I opened the Views folder and within that I opened the Movies folder. The Movies folder contains the files:

- create.cshtml
- delete.cshtml
- details.cshtml
- edit.cshtml
- index.cshtml

Each of these files contained references to Title, ReleaseDate, Genre, and Price. So I updated each of these to their new name to match the Movie.cs names.

Expected results: I expected the app to display the new column names (Name, Date, Email, Contract).

Actual results: when I save and run, the home page opens fine, but when I click to navigate to the Movies page, I get the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: m.Contract'.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(int rc, sqlite3 db)

The Internal Server Error page provides the (presumably) location(bolded below) of the problem and some red text to help me pinpoint the problem (RED ->):

### MvcMovie.Controllers.MoviesController.Index() in MoviesController.cs

```
    _context = context;
}
//End of Constructor
// GET: Movies
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  RED ->  return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
}

// GET: Movies/Details/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
```

What I've tried:
I've double-checked that I updated all the names correctly in the Movie.cs file, and in the Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Index files.
I've also tried going into the Controllers folder, and updating the MoviesController.cs file with the new names (Name, Date, Email, Contract). Below I've included the contents of the MoviesController.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcMovie.Data;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{//Constructor using D.I. to inject database context into the controller
    public class MoviesController: Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

        public MoviesController(MvcMovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        //End of Constructor
        // GET: Movies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Movies/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Movies/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,Date,Email,Contract")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(movie);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Name,Date,Email,Contract")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (id != movie.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(movie);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MovieExists(movie.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool MovieExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Movie.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

The things I've tried do not change the error. The app was working normally before I updated the names in all the files. I greatly appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you need to add a migration and update the database. At the moment your changes on the model wont reflect the table structure of the database.

Comment: To make this clear, it's add another migration. Don't remove the old one. Then perform the update database

Comment: Looks like `Movie` class is mapped to a database table and its properties are mapped to columns of the table. That means the table name/classname and propertynames/columnames should match. You are changing the property names, which causes the SQL queries to be generated with those column names and those new names are not found in the database table. that' why you  are getting this error. Do you just want to change what is displayed in the UI? or you also want to change the columnames in the database?

Comment: @RobWhite Thank you!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would be fine with just changing what is displayed in the UI, and leaving the column names the same, if that would be easier. Could you recommend the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you do this you will have to drop and re-create the database - the database still has the old names. The other way is to use code first migrations and add migrations, the migrations will fix the names (rename them) when you create them - another thing you can try is add a data annotation attribute to the property like :

```
   [Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```